# Prove $\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}y\cos\frac{u\pi}v-x\sin\frac{u\pi}v=(-2)^{-v+1}\sum_{w=0}^{\lfloor\frac{v-1}2\rfloor}(-1)^w\binom{v}{2w+1}x^{v-2w-1}y^{2w+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

> Prove the following trigonometric equation
> $$\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}y\cos{\frac{u\pi}{v}}-x\sin{\frac{u\pi}{v}}=(-2)^{-v+1}\sum_{w=0}^{\lfloor\frac{v-1}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^{w}\binom{v}{2w+1}x^{v-2w-1}y^{2w+1}$$

The right term is my observation and might not be typed correct. But when the left term is equal to $0$, the image would be $v$ perfectly distributed line like this ($v=9$):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from

$$\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}
\left[ y \cos (u\pi/v) - x \sin(u\pi/v) \right]$$

we put $y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sin\theta$ to get

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v
\prod_{u=0}^{v-1} \sin(\theta-u\pi/v)
\\ = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{1}{2^v i^v}
\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}
[\exp(i(\theta-u\pi/v)) - \exp(-i(\theta-u\pi/v))]
\\ = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{1}{2^v i^v}
\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}
\exp(-i(\theta-u\pi/v))
\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}
[\exp(2i(\theta-u\pi/v)) - 1]
\\ = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{1}{2^v i^v}
\exp(-iv\theta) \exp(+i(v-1)\pi/2)
\\ \times \prod_{u=0}^{v-1}
[\exp(2i\theta) \exp(-u2\pi i/v)) - 1].$$

Now observe that

$$\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}
[z \exp(-u 2\pi i/v)) - 1]
\\ = \prod_{u=0}^{v-1} \exp(-u 2\pi i/v)
\prod_{u=0}^{v-1} [z - \exp(u 2\pi i/v)]
= \exp(-\pi i (v-1)) (z^v-1).$$

Replace $z$ by $\exp(2i\theta)$ to get

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{1}{2^v i^v}
\exp(-iv\theta) \exp(-i(v-1)\pi/2)
(\exp(2iv\theta)-1)
\\ = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\frac{\exp(iv\theta)-\exp(-iv\theta)}{2i}
\\ = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\sin(v\theta)
\\ =  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\Im \exp(iv\theta)
=  \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\Im \exp(iv\theta) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^v
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\Im \sum_{q=0}^v {v\choose q} (\exp(i\theta)\sqrt{x^2+y^2} -1)^q
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\Im \sum_{q=0}^v {v\choose q} (x+iy-1)^q.$$

The coefficient on $y^p$ where for now $0\le p\le v$ is

$$\frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}}
\Im \sum_{q=0}^v {v\choose q} {q\choose p} i^p (x-1)^{q-p}.$$

Observe that

$${v\choose q} {q\choose p} =
\frac{v!}{(v-q)! \times p! \times (q-p)!}
= {v\choose p} {v-p\choose v-q}$$

and we obtain

$$\frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}} {v\choose p}
\Im \sum_{q=0}^v {v-p\choose v-q} i^p (x-1)^{q-p}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}} {v\choose p}
\Im i^p \sum_{q=p}^v {v-p\choose v-q} (x-1)^{q-p}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}} {v\choose p}
\Im i^p \sum_{q=0}^{v-p} {v-p\choose v-p-q} (x-1)^q
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}} {v\choose p}
\Im i^p \sum_{q=0}^{v-p} {v-p\choose q} (x-1)^q
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}} {v\choose p}
\Im i^p x^{v-p}.$$

We see from the powers of the imaginary unit that for the imaginary part not to vanish we must have $p=2w+1$ where $0\le 2w+1\le v$ and we get

$$\frac{(-1)^{v-1}}{2^{v-1}} {v\choose 2w+1} (-1)^w x^{v-2w-1}.$$

Summing this over all admissible $w$ will finally yield

$$(-2)^{1-v} \sum_{w=0}^{\lfloor (v-1)/2 \rfloor}
{v\choose 2w+1} (-1)^w x^{v-2w-1} y^{2w+1}.$$

Comment: Excellent answer! From Sebastiano's answer I could only deduce the coefficient of $y^p$ vanishes for p even. For those may still have questions: note $a^p=((a-1)+1)^p$ and expand binomially.

Comment: Also apparently once we reach $(x^2+y^2)^{v/2}(-2)^{1-v}\sin(v\theta)$ we can just use Trigonometric Identities(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476369/trigonometric-identities-for-sin-nx-and-cos-nx?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To prove the identity

$$\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}y\cos{\frac{u\pi}{v}}-x\sin{\frac{u\pi}{v}}=(-2)^{-v+1}\sum_{w=0}^{\lfloor\frac{v-1}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^{w}\binom{2w+1}{v}x^{v-2w-1}y^{2w+1}$$

you can use the Euler's formula for cosine and sine.
$$\cos x = {e^{ix} + e^{-ix} \over 2},
\sin x = {e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \over 2i}$$
You have like starting point

$$\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}y\cos{\frac{u\pi}{v}}-x\sin{\frac{u\pi}{v}}=\prod_{u=0}^{v-1}\left(y\,{e^{i\frac{u\pi}{v}} + e^{-i\frac{u\pi}{v}} \over 2}-x\,{e^{i\frac{u\pi}{v}} - e^{-i\frac{u\pi}{v}} \over 2i}\right)$$